# How to Retrieve individual JSON values from Firebase Database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have a firebase node that is dbref = firebase.ref('/Transfer_Request/{pushID]/').

And the client writes two values; from_ID and to_ID to dbref. How do I get the individual values of the from_ID and to_ID from Firebase Cloud functions?

[image: My database]

My code:

```
exports.TransferTicket = functions.database.ref('/Transfer_Request/{pushID}').onWrite((event) => {

  const original = event.data.val();
  const from_ID = original.from_ID;
  const to_email_ID = original.to_ID;

  //search for to_email ID
  return admin.database().set("A transfer request was just made");

});
```

I'm getting two errors:

1)

> TypeError: admin.database(...).set is not a function at
>   exports.TransferTicket.functions.database.ref.onWrite
>   (/user_code/index.js:41:25) at Object.
>   (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
>   at next (native) at
>   /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
>   at __awaiter
>   (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
>   at cloudFunction
>   (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
>   at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:716:24 at process._tickDomainCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

2)

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of null at
>   exports.TransferTicket.functions.database.ref.onWrite
>   (/user_code/index.js:35:25) at Object.
>   (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
>   at next (native) at
>   /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
>   at __awaiter
>   (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
>   at cloudFunction
>   (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
>   at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:716:24 at process._tickDomainCallback
>   (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem comes from the fact that when doing the following you miss a Firebase `Reference`.

```
return admin.database().set("A transfer request was just made");
```

You should do:

```
admin.database().ref('...the path where you want to write...').set("A transfer request was just made");
```

For more details, see the doc for [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference) and [Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Database) .

The second problem comes from the fact that since the new release of the version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions, the syntax has changed. See this doc [item](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff).

You should modify your code as follows:

```
exports.TransferTicket = functions.database.ref('/Transfer_Request/{pushID}').onWrite((change, context) => {

    const original = change.after.val();

    const from_ID = original.from_ID;
    console.log(from_ID);
    const to_email_ID = original.to_ID;
    console.log(to_email_ID);

    return admin.database().ref('...path...').set("A transfer request was just made")
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        //...
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm inputting the value at .ref('/Transfer_Request/{pushID]/') as {"from_ID" : "afd@gm.com", "to_ID" : "afds1@gm.com"}. Now, how do I assign the values of 'from_ID' and 'to_ID' to different variables in my program? Because it says that 'change.after.val()' is null. Can this be because it's not one value but a json object that's being written?

Comment: Your javascript object seems correct. When you look at the database from the Firebase console; do you see the correct values for from_ID and to_ID?

Comment: Can you add to your post an extract of your database for the `Transfer_Request` node?

Comment: Uploaded as you asked!

Comment: The only weird think I see is that on your print screen you miss a double quote at the end of the ar@gm.com and sd@gm.com. For the rest it should work. I've updated my answer with some console logs. What do you see in the Functions log? I also update the code with a catch for the set() method, in order to handle possible promise rejections.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172904/discussion-between-arjun-ram-and-renaud-tarnec).